# JOGL glTexSubImage2D eats up to 100% cpu and takes ages

Tags: opengl, jogl

I've faced with the issue that execution time for single gl.glTexSubImage2D() call takes 0.1-0.2sec while running on Linux and eating 100% of cpu. On mac it is all fine.

The call arguments are the following:

```
gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, GL2.GL_RED, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, data);
```

Textures setup is the following:

```
void glCreateClearTex(GL gl, int target, int fmt, int format, int type, int filter, int w, int h, int val) {
    float fval = 0;
    int stride;
    if (w == 0)
        w = 1;
    if (h == 0)
        h = 1;
    stride = 2/*2048*/ * 2;
    ByteBuffer init = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(stride * h/*2048*/);
    glAdjustAlignment(gl, stride);
    gl.glPixelStorei(GL2.GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, w);
    gl.glTexImage2D(target, 0, fmt, w, h, 0, format, type, init);
    gl.glTexParameterf(target, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_PRIORITY, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexParameteri(target, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameteri(target, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameteri(target, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameteri(target, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.glTexParameterfv(target, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[] { fval, fval, fval, fval }));
}
```

Mplayer doing same work natively runs just fine. glxgears runs ok but also takes up 100%. This may be the sign of OpenGL setup issues but glxinfo and others report that it is hw rendering. Graphic Card is ATI FirePro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Jogl has two variants of gl.glTexSubImage2D(). One is using data ptr to upload to pbo and later to GPU, another one - offset inside already prepared pbo. My mistake was that I uploaded data twice and this somehow caused major slowdown on linux.

So the fix is to upload data to pbo and then upload it to GPU with gl.glTexSubImage2D() using offset inside pbo.